# Public class members in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I am very new to coffeescript, and I have been trying to find a way to make publicly accessible class members. If I run the following code:

```
class cow
  n = 7
  moo: -> 
    alert("moo")

bessie = new cow
alert(bessie.n);
```

It will show that `bessie.n` is undefined. The only solution I can find is to make getters and setters like `n: -> n` and `setN: (value) -> n = value`. I then must use function calls instead of simple property accesses. This feels cumbersome for a language which sells itself based on syntactic sugar.

Is there something I missed in the documentation that makes it easier to make classes with simple public members? What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's no different from setting methods.

Just try this

```
class cow
  n: 7
```

Doing only

```
class cow
  n = 7
```

Will just set private variable inside the class closure.

Use *try coffeescript* link on http://coffeescript.org/ to see what it compiles to.

Comment: I put `n=7` in to initialize it, but Now I see that is more analagous to a private variable. `n: 7` is more like a property. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that setting "n = 7" is common to all instances of the class.

Comment: So its like a private static? Good to know.

Comment: Exactly. Fun fact: `class` is the only way to create a function in CoffeeScript, other than `->` and `=>`. Unlike with `->` or `=>`, the function runs immediately, but it's otherwise normal. It's only when you use the key-value syntax `:` to define prototype properties (and `constructor`) that its specialness shines through.

Answer (score 0):

when you need a private member, you typically can't use a private static member in its place.

The concept of private variables is easily implemented via Crockfords suggestions, but this isn't a proper CoffeeScript class and as such you can't extend it.  The winner is that you get an object with methods where no one else can read/write your variable making it a little more foolproof.  Note you don't use the 'new' keyword (which Crockford considers a bad practice anyway)

```
Counter = (count, name) ->
    count += 1
    return {
        incr : ->
            count = count + 1
        getCount : ->
            count
    }

c1 = Counter 0, "foo"
c2 = Counter 0, "bar"
c3 = Counter 0, "baz"

console.log c1.getCount() # return 1 regardless of instantiation number
console.log c1.count # will return undefined
```